# No Such Element Exception in the middle of a text file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I am currently trying to write Java code that will read a .txt file containing various trivia questions, and store the prompt, correct answer, and the other answer choices in a Question object. Write now I am not worried about putting those values in an object, only scanning the questions properly. This code is supposed to go scan through a .txt file. If the line starts with '#', then that means its question prompt and then it continues to scan the few lines and store the answer choices. If the answer choices only have two options, it skips over that question (only want 4 option multiple choice questions). By the end, every question in the file should be printed out in their original format in the .txt file.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextReader {
    ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File("animals.txt");
        TextReader.parseFile(file);

    }

    public static void parseFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        String category = file.getName();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            String string = s.nextLine();
            if(string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(0) == '#'){ //checks for start of a question
                System.out.println(string);
                String correct = s.nextLine(); //scans correct answer
                System.out.println(correct);
                String a = s.nextLine(); //scans answers choices
                System.out.println(a);
                String b = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(b);
                String c = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(c);
                if(c.isEmpty()){ //checks if only has two answers (i.e true or false, yes or no), then goes to next questions
                    s.nextLine();
                }else{
                    String d = s.nextLine();//scans last answer choice
                    System.out.println(d);

                }

            }
        }


    }



}
```

I'm using [this .txt file right now](https://github.com/uberspot/OpenTriviaQA/blob/master/categories/animals). It reads everything good up until line 690, where the code throws a NoSuchElementException error in the middle of reading option C for the question.

```
#Q The Chihuahua Gidget is famous for what reason?
^ It was a mascot for Taco Bell.
A Paris Hilton has it as a pet.
B It was a fill-in mascot for the Georgia Bulldogs.
C It was a mascot for Ta
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
```

And this happens regardless of whether or not I delete this question, or if I delete every question before it and put it at the start, I keep getting this NoSuchElement exception even though it's in the middle of the .txt file. Everything after this point in the file just throws that error and I'm not sure why and this occurs for the other .txt files as well.

Comment: I've tried your code and it's worked fine for me, also when I moved the _#Q The Chihuahua Gidget is famous for what reason?_ question into the end of the file.